# Using Stripe to manually create invoices

Tags: java, rest, stripe-payments, invoice

I would like to send invoices to my customers via stripe. I have created a stripe account which is still in test mode and I have successfully created invoices using stripes api's (invoices created without subscriptions)

It seems that even though the invoices gets created it is not sent in email to customer. I can see the invoice in my Stripe dashboard. I can manually press a button in the dashboard which will send the invoice to desired email.

I was wondering if there is any way of getting the invoices emailed immediately once they are created via api call ? Also is there any mechanism to add a pay with stripe option to invoice emails ?

Answer (score 0):

See the code below for how to manually send invoices. Use the sendInvoice method:

```
Invoice invoice = Invoice.retrieve("in_1E3mnPAO1KumKYA2o44P3Ehb");
invoice.sendInvoice();
```

As for sending invoices that includes a hosted link to pay with stripe, see the API doc here about using the 'billing' option https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create?lang=java#create_invoice-billing